# Помогите найти ошибку в коде по поиску определенного числа

Tags: c++, математика, факторизация

У меня дан класс с функцией для поиска чисел в заданных пределах от м до н.
Подходящим числом называется то число, например 42.
Мы берем все делители этого числа, то есть (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42) и возводим каждое число в квадрат. После все эти числа ссумируются и получается одно число. Мы проверяем является ли получившееся число квадратным. Если да, то 42 и только что найденная сумма заносятся как пара в вектор. Но у меня почему то заноситтся 4 и 361.... Подходящие числа заносятся в вектор типа пара.

```
const long long squares[] = {
    0, 1, 4, 9,
    16, 25, 36, 49,
    64, 81, 100, 121,
    144, 169, 196, 225,
    256, 289, 324, 361,
    400, 441, 484, 529,
    576, 625, 676, 729,
    784, 841, 900, 961,
    1024, 1089, 1156, 1225,
    1296, 1369, 1444, 1521,
    1600, 1681, 1764, 1849,
    1936, 2025, 2116, 2209,
    2304, 2401, 2500, 2601,
    2704, 2809, 2916, 3025,
    3136, 3249, 3364, 3481,
    3600, 3721, 3844, 3969,
    4096, 4225, 4356, 4489,
    4624, 4761, 4900, 5041,
    5184, 5329, 5476, 5625,
    5776, 5929, 6084, 6241,
    6400, 6561, 6724, 6889,
    7056, 7225, 7396, 7569,
    7744, 7921, 8100, 8281,
    8464, 8649, 8836, 9025,
    9216, 9409, 9604, 9801,
    10000, 10201, 10404, 10609,
    10816, 11025, 11236, 11449,
    11664, 11881, 12100, 12321,
    12544, 12769, 12996, 13225,
    13456, 13689, 13924, 14161,
    14400, 14641, 14884, 15129,
    15376, 15625, 15876, 16129,
    16384, 16641, 16900, 17161,
    17424, 17689, 17956, 18225,
    18496, 18769, 19044, 19321,
    19600, 19881, 20164, 20449,
    20736, 21025, 21316, 21609,
    21904, 22201, 22500, 22801,
    23104, 23409, 23716, 24025,
    24336, 24649, 24964, 25281,
    25600, 25921, 26244, 26569,
    26896, 27225, 27556, 27889,
    28224, 28561, 28900, 29241,
    29584, 29929, 30276, 30625,
    30976, 31329, 31684, 32041,
    32400, 32761, 33124, 33489,
    33856, 34225, 34596, 34969,
    35344, 35721, 36100, 36481,
    36864, 37249, 37636, 38025,
    38416, 38809, 39204, 39601,
    40000, 40401, 40804, 41209,
    41616, 42025, 42436, 42849,
    43264, 43681, 44100, 44521,
    44944, 45369, 45796, 46225,
    46656, 47089, 47524, 47961,
    48400, 48841, 49284, 49729,
    50176, 50625, 51076, 51529,
    51984, 52441, 52900, 53361,
    53824, 54289, 54756, 55225,
    55696, 56169, 56644, 57121,
    57600, 58081, 58564, 59049,
    59536, 60025, 60516, 61009,
    61504, 62001, 62500, 63001,
    63504, 64009, 64516, 65025
};
inline bool is_square(long long x) {
    const long long *p = squares;

    if (p[128] <= x) p += 128;
    if (p[ 64] <= x) p +=  64;
    if (p[ 32] <= x) p +=  32;
    if (p[ 16] <= x) p +=  16;
    if (p[  8] <= x) p +=   8;
    if (p[  4] <= x) p +=   4;
    if (p[  2] <= x) p +=   2;
    if (p[  1] <= x) p +=   1;

    return (p[0] == x);
}

    class SumSquaredDivisors
    {
    public:
        static std::vector<std::pair<long long, long long>> listSquared(long long m, long long n)
        {
         vector<long long>table;
         vector<pair<long long, long long>>result;

         for(m;m<=n;++m)
         {
          for(long long k{1};k<=m;++k)
            if((m%k)==0)table.push_back(k); 
          long long sum{};
          for(int i{};i<table.size();++i)
          {
            table[i]*=table[i];
            sum+=table[i];
          }
            pair<long long,long long>m_pair;
            m_pair=make_pair(m,sum);
            if(is_square(sum)){result.push_back(m_pair);}
         }
         return result;
         }
    };
```

Comment: Не первый раз уже... Ну сколько можно называть числа - цифрами... А по сути - знаете, продраться через *"я установил что цифра будет подходящей если ее члены которые являются делителями, сначала каждый возводиться в квадрат потом все это суммируется и если сумма будет извлекаться из корня без остатка то это число подходит"* - напишите понятнее. Сумма квадратов делителей числа (всех? простых? включая 1, нет? само число?  должна быть точным квадратом - что-то типа этого? Да и проверка на квадратичность у вас какая-то странная...

Comment: Просто много чисел, я решил что так будет быстрее чем делать еще один луп. К примеру переберать числа от 250 - 500. будут огромные числа...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за отклик, я уже поправил тайтл вопроса. Простите что так долго.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, в простейшем (переборном) варианте это выглядит так:

```
unsigned long long is_ok(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i*i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            sum += i*i;
            if (i*i != n) sum += (n/i)*(n/i);
        }
    }
    unsigned long long sq = sqrt(sum)+0.5;
    if (sq*sq == sum) return sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Работающую программу можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ideone.com/Tggim6).

Comment: Я уже не выдержал и посмотрел решение) Но все же не могу понять где моя ошибка. Не могу смотреть на код который уже 100 раз пересматривал... СПАСИБО Harry)

Comment: Да как минимум вы `table` делителей для нового числе не чистите и просто добавляете и добавляете все новые делители... Да и ваш метод проверки на квадраты работает для очень небольшого количества чисел. Вставьте `table.clear();` перед `for` для `k`.

Comment: пхах) Боже, я глупый человек. Спасибо вам, исправил, все работает) Я удалю вопрос. 0 смысловой нагрузки для других